# In a WPF app, how to change the AutoSize property (for a label) to false?

Tags: c#, wpf, autosize

I'm trying to learn C# using "Head First C#". I'm only on chapter 2, making a WPF app, and its telling me to drag a label from the toolbox onto the window. That should be no problem.

But now it wants me to change both the AutoSize and TextAlign properties to False and MiddleCenter, respectively. Problem is, neither are listed anywhere in the properties window. I even tried sorting everything by name and using the search bar, still nothing.

I have been looking for over an hour and even msdn tells me "Oh Yeah! just set the AutoSize property to False". I'm still very new to all this, I don't even know what the properties are even supposed to do yet, because I can't finish the exercise.

Comment: Not related, but seems you choose wrong book for learning c# if you stack with a problem which has nothing to do with c#

Comment: @Fabio: well, it is "head first". :) From the Oxford Dictionary: "head first: adjective, •without sufficient forethought". See also http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Head-first

Comment: To the OP: the property names you describe are found on the Winforms `Label` control, but not the WPF `Label` control. Are you sure the book you are reading is discussing WPF?

Answer (score 0):

Wpf lable does not have AutoSize Property. TextBlock without Width property can be use instead.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes they're hard to spot, so it might be helpful to click the `Alphabetical` sort button (and make sure that the next button, `Properties` is selected). And of course make sure the `label` is selected at the top of the properties window:

[image]

Comment: In WPF not in Windows Forms.